# Some of the Actor messages are missing --AKKA FSM

Tags: scala, akka, fsm, state-machine

Here is the sample code flow:

```
class FSMActor{
  when(Idle) {
    case Event(Start, Uninitialized) =>
    case Event(InitMap(inMap), t @ EvaluteRuleMap(v, c)) =>
      logger.info(s"State = $stateName, Event = Event(_, InitMap(inMap))")
      goto(EVALRule) using t.copy(ruleMap = inMap)
  }
  when(EVALRule) {
    case Event(RowMap(m), t @ EvaluteRuleMap(v, c)) =>
    logger.debug("input row map m " + m)
    **if ( <somecondition> ) {  // If comment this if-else block, I could see rowMaps being received.
      logger.debug(s"Moving to State Trigger x=$x")
      goto(TriggerRule) using t.copy(ruleMap = x.get)
    } else {
        logger.debug(s"staying in EVALRule, x = $x")
        stay
    }**
  }

  when(TriggerRule) {
    case Event(_, _) => ....
  }
 }
}
```

When the control in in "EVALRule" state, It will keep receiving streams maps(RowMap) and based on some computation, it moves to trigger rule.

Unfortunately for some weird reason, some of the incoming RowMaps are not being received at "case Event(RowMap(m), t @ EvaluteRuleMap(v, c)) =>" and 
If I comment the code bock (bolded in the above code) then I could see all incoming rowmaps being received. 
Could anyone let me know why is so? I've been trying to find the cause but couldn't get it to.
Appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When `if ( <somecondition> )` is true, you are moving to the `TriggerRule` state. In that state you are looking for messages of type `EVENT` instead of `Event` (all caps). So the message is not handled by the FSM.

In general, when missing messages in FSM, the best way to debug is to write a `whenUnhandled` block with a log/print statement to see what messages are not handled by the states you have defined.

Comment: Sorry, That's typo, its just Event not EVENT. corrected it.

Comment: Can you put a whenUnhandled block and see if there are any messages coming there?

Comment: Yes, I'd actually had that whenUnhandled{  } block but I still don't see any of the messages going there. I also have OnTransition { } block where I could see state transition happening  but something strange behavior in toggling between states.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

There was some issue with message handling in the code itself, we debugged it and fixed the issue, now its working seamlessly.